# How to use += operator in a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I am able to built a wordCount dictionary by means of:

```
dicc = {}
for word in splitt:
    if word not in dicc:
        dicc[word]=0
    if word in dicc:
        dicc[word]+=1
```

I am trying to do it in a dictionary comprehension.
The following statement is valid:

```
countDicc = {word:(0 if word not in countDicc else +1) for word in splitt}
```

Obviously I need `+=1` to have the dictionary serve its purpose, however, that statement is invalid; how can I implement the `+=` in a dictionary comprehension?

Comment: why not use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: You can use `dict.get` method and use a default value as 0: `dicc[word] = dicc.get(word,0) + 1` . What you are trying to achieve is not possible by comprehension, I beleive.

Comment: A dictionary comprehension can not accumulate values. If a key is appears more than once in the comprehension, only the last is used. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Answer (score 3):

Use Counter

```
from collections import Counter

dicc = dict(Counter(splitt))
print(dicc)
```

Comment: Thanks. But It is about the exploration of what is possible with a dictionary comprehension; the purpose of the input output is not the point.